Filter for date not reflected correctly in OData V2 service
I'm using the DateRangeSelection element to select my data at backend. I pick the date "01.07.2024".
This value can also be found in the filter object:

The corresponding service implementation is receiving a different date, and I don't know why:

The IV_FILTER_STRING in the OData service corresponds to the filter tab:
( ( PurchaseOrderDate ge '20240106' ) and ( PurchaseOrderDate le '20240106' ) )

Seems to be a strange behavior to me!

So maybe as an overall info ... (Sorry for the mess here but I'm really new to stack overflow and not so familiar with the logic yet).
I changed from string to ui5Date format. Annotations are Edm.DateTime.
Even if I choose 01.07.2024 - 04.07.2024 I will receive in SAP 30.06.2024 - 04.07.2024
If I only pick 01.07.2024 I will receive 30.06.2024 - 01.07.2024. I believe it is related to time zones?? Because I don't have a time so the system will use 0 as the time??


In the served OData V2 $metadata, make sure that the entity property PurchaseOrderDate is of type Edm.DateTime and annotated with sap:display-format="Date". Refer to "Dates, Times, Timestamps, and Time Zones" - SAPUI5 documentation.

Rather than creating Filters instances manually, try accessing existing filters that have been created already by the control. SmartFilterBar, for example, provides the API getFilters.

If you have to create the Filter by yourself, make sure that each Filter value is:

not a string but an instance of JavaScript Date (preferrably created with sap/ui/core/date/UI5Date.getInstance).
not 00:00:00 in time if your local time differs. With an OData list or tree binding, the framework will automatically convert the given time to UTC when constructing the $filter query for the request.



See also the SmartFilterBar documentation "Date Filter Fields". If the documentation lacks in what you're looking for, ask for an enhancement in https://github.com/SAP-docs/sapui5.

Good morning .. thank you for your reply ... yes it is set to "Edm.DateTime" and also annotated with Date ... that seems to be ok.

I changed from string to the corresponding method to retrieve the from and to date. getSecondDateValue and getDateValue.
This returns a UI5Date object which is fine.
But when I choose 01.07.2024 to 07.07.2024: Dates are correct in js data but in SAP I receive: 30.06.2024 to 07.07.2024 ... the first day is wrong

@sguski With which SAPUI5 version is the app currently running? You can view the version by pressing [Ctrl] + [Left Alt] + [Shift] + [P] in the app.

@sguski Just updated my answer. Let us know if it helped.

Try with below filter, passing dates as js date object.
new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path: "YOUR_DATE_FIELD_TO_FILTER",
        operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT,
        value1: new Date("01.07.2024"),
        value2: new Date("01.07.2024")
})

